# Remove Lots of index pages from google bot from same directory.

Tags: htaccess, seo, robots.txt, googlebot, google-search-console

My question is about Google bot, seo and webmaster.
may be this is not right place for ask, but if person not know so where he place his question  he doesn't know!!!

If you know my question's answer so please first give me answer,than mark my question like or dislike, i not depend on question likes. i want some knowledge.

i think If stackoverflow allow to insert seo tag in question so this is right place..

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

I search and read many post for 1 month, but i can't find any help full material for my problem...

In my website there is only 2000 pages, but when i search my site in google `site:collectioncoupons.com` google show me 9000 pages.

1 month agao i remove 1600 pages, and i want to remove all these pages,

URL looks like that,

```
domain.com/store/1
domain.com/store/2
domain.com/store/3
...
domain.com/store/2000
i want to remove pages from domain.com/stores/1 to domain.com/stores/1600
```

But how i remove all 1600 pages without removing stores directory?

//////////////////////////////

one other problem with my index pages.

when i search `site:collectioncoupons.com` google show 20pages.
when i search `site:collectioncoupons.com/out` then google show 300 pages that in "out" directory and same with other directories.

Is this problem? why google not show all pages on home page. `site:collectioncoupons.com`

/////////////////////////////////

Please tell me one more thing, when i search my domain with site: google show results 9,490
[image]
but i have only 2000 pages, so what are other 7,490 pages?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Answer (score 2):

You can tell Google to allow the /store directory, but not /store/???. For example, in your robots.txt file:

```
User-agent: Googlebot
Allow: /store$
Allow: /store/$
Disallow: /store/
```

This tells Googlebot that `/store` and `/store/` are allowed. The `$` at the end means, "end of url." But if you have `/store/1` or `/store/` followed by anything else, then disallow it.

I don't know the answers to your other questions. Perhaps there are alternate URLs to your pages, or URLs that have query string parameters. You have the search results, why not look at the URLs that Google is reporting and see how the URLs differ?